# 500.79 Internal Server Error - The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred

Tags: azure, deployment, openid, internal-server-error

When running my MVC website locally it works fine - the website uses 'Cloud - Single Organization' authorization.

Once I've deployed to Azure I get an error on the homepage saying 'The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.'

When looking at the streaming logs in Azure I can see I'm getting an 'HTTP Error 500.79 - Internal Server Error'

Under the detailed error information, I get the following information:
Module:    EasyAuthModule_32bit
Notification:      AuthenticateRequest
Handler:       ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code:    0x80004005

Under the detailed information I get the error:
Error Failed to download OpenID configuration from 'https://localhost:44378/.well-known/openid-configuration': Unable to connect to the remote server.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: If anyone else is experiencing this problem, I ended up having to create a new app in Azure. Not the ideal solution but it's the only way I could get around the error.